# Cycle Count [Python]

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, trend

I have data that fluctuates up and down. Each time it returns to the value (let's say 9.77), that will count that as a cycle. Each input value should thus correspond with a cycle. Here is the Python code so far, but getting an error. Or what is a more efficient way of doing this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
data= [9.77,10.38,10.38,10.68,10.07,10.68,10.38,10.07,10.07,10.07,10.38,9.77,10.07,10.07, 10.38,10.07,10.38,10.07,10.38,10.38,10.68,9.77]
plt.plot(data)
data = np.array(data)
labels = []
searchval = 9.77
ii = np.where(data == searchval)[0]
print(f'New Cycle markers: {ii}')
t = True
cycle = 1
while t == True:
    labels = [cycle] * ii[cycle]
    labels.append(labels)
    cycle = cycle + 1

ERROR:
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-21-7cfe5b673865>", line 4, in <module>
    labels = [cycle] * ii[cycle]
IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3
```

Ideal output:
Cycle 1 would be 11 times, and cycle 2 will be 21 times assuming a cycle is defined whenever we reach 9.77 marker.

```
labels = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: `t` is true and never changes, so your loop will run infinitely.  No matter how large `ii` is, `cycle` will keep growing  beyond it.  Why not `for cycle in range(len(ii)):`?